# Adding a line of text to an xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file, edit

I have a folder of 31,000 xml files and I need to add a reference to a stylesheet at the top of each file.

Is there a programmatic way to open each file, add a line of code at the top, save it and go to the next file?

Comment: Try with sed s/^initial/yourline/ -i * (http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: Yes, it's completely possible. Have you tried anything to make this happen? What happened, or where are you running into trouble?

Comment: You have a lot of files in that folder.  You will need to read the directory and process each filename.  That is too many for shell expansion.  Are you windows or linux?

Comment: As above: Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Unix-like system, this is very simple to do using a BASH for loop and the `cat` tool.

Let's say you have a file, "header.txt" which contains the line you want to add to the top of each XML file. Your loop would look like this:

```
for file in *.xml
do
  cat header.txt $file > ${file}_new
  mv ${file}_new $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

*Clean* would be to use an XML-aware tool.

```
<!-- save as add_stylesheet.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- at the top level of the document... --> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- unless a stylesheet reference already exists -->
        <xsl:if test="not(processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet'))">
            <!-- ...create the stylesheet reference --> 
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">
                <xsl:text>type="text/xsl" href="foo.xsl"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:processing-instruction>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- ...then copy the rest of the document --> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then, under Windows

```
for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir /b *.xml') do msxsl "%f" add_stylesheet.xsl -o "%f"
```

This uses [msxsl.exe, available for free from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714).

Note that this command overwrites the original files. Use `-o "output\%f"` to write files to a different directory ("output", in this case) instead.

---

The same thing would work under Linux, the command line would differ.

```
find . -type f -name \*.xml -exec xsltproc -o '{}' add_stylesheet.xsl '{}' \;
```

Using `-o './output/{}'` will prevent overwriting the files here, too.

Comment: Using `dir /b` in a folder with 31,000 files will cause a very long delay before anything happens.  Maybe an hour or more. :)  If you redirect the dir into a file and parse the file directly then it will work as intended.

Comment: @foxidrive That's wrong. I've just created a sample directory with 50,000 files in it and `dir /b` starts to output rows immediately and finishes in one or two seconds. The second run (everything is cached) runs even faster.

Comment: Yes, you are correct for 31,000 files.  The effect does occur and is very pronounced, increasing with the number of files, but it takes in the region of 150,000 files (1 minute delay here) and increases as the number of files goes higher.  My mistake in the number of files.

Comment: And in the timescale! I know `cmd.exe` is not the fastest terminal out there, but "an hour or more" sounded very unlikely to me. ;)

Comment: Try a couple of million files.  I think you'll find there is a fair delay.

Comment: Yes, I would expect some delay there. Still not an hour, though. But that's not the scale we were talking about here, so I think we can rest this case.

Comment: If you're interested in this bug, try this test case.  250,000 files for a 35 minute delay tested here.  Script here: http://pastebin.com/J6yTJwrs  I recalled some further detail (but can't find my posts on the topic).  The issue isn't just the number of files but also the length of the path\filename for recursive searches, as the buffer used affects the severity of the issue.  If you want to bump up the number of files you should see that it is exponential in nature.

Comment: JFTR a second test with the same line length and 400,000 files took 92 minutes before it started the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows and you want to add a new line at the beginning of each file then this should work:

Test it on some sample files.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.xml) do (
  >"%%a.tmp" echo ^<new header/^>
  type "%%a" >> "%%a.tmp"
)
del *.xml
ren *.tmp *.xml
```